# How to access an inner enum classes overwritten methods?

Tags: java, enums

What code is needed for the main to access the getPrice() method ?

I can access the public enum type with the built in values(); function

but cant figure out how to print the prices , thanks

```
public enum Drink {
    GUINNESS(Type.STOUT), 
    COLA(Type.COLA);

    private Type type;

    private Drink(Type type) {
        this.type = type;
    }

    private enum Type {
        STOUT {
            @Override
            public double getPrice() {
                return 4.0;
            }
        },
        COLA {
            @Override
            public double getPrice() {
                return 2.0;
            }
        };

        public abstract double getPrice();
    }

}
```

Comment: Why are you using nested enums, anyway?  One enum (`Type`) seems like it'd be plenty here, and you wouldn't run into weird use case issues like this.

Comment: Make the `Type` enum public (or at least non-private). `Drink.Type.STOUT.getPrice();`

Answer (score 2):

You have to add a getter for the `price` in the `Drink` enum.

```
public double getPrice() {
    return type.getPrice();
}
```

And then you can do:

```
Drink cola = Drink.COLA;
double price = cola.getPrice();
```

Answer (score 2):

You can't access the private inner enum outside the `public enum`, you can however delegate the method:

```
public enum Drink {

    GUINNESS(Type.STOUT), 
    COLA(Type.COLA);

    private Type type;

    private Drink(Type type) {
        this.type = type;
    }

    public double getPrice() {
        return type.getPrice();
    }

    private enum Type {
        STOUT {
            @Override
            public double getPrice() {
                return 4.0;
            }
        },
        COLA {
            @Override
            public double getPrice() {
                return 2.0;
            }
        };

        public abstract double getPrice();
    }

}
```

You define the same method in the `enum Drink`:

```
public double getPrice() {
    return type.getPrice();
}
```

Comment: True, if the inner enum is public... (modified). Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can't, since another class can't see the nested enum at all. You could add a delegating copy to the top-level enum.